# Entity Framework in Class Library without outside references

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to figure out how to add Entity Framework 6 into a separate class library without having the web.config inside the client project knowing anything about DB connections of its helper class libraries. The reason for that is that a single client will be able to talk to different components, which will all have wildly different functionalities and DBs. Because of this I want to expose a basic set of common functions that the Class Libraries will expose without the Client application having to care about how they get that information.

Surely this must be possible. Am I mistaken?

This is the planned structure:

- Web API Project

  - Class Library 1 (DB1)
  - Class Library 2 (DB2)
  - Class Library 3 (might or might not contain DB)

I have tried moving the EF references to a separate project but cannot seem to be able to make a connection to the DB unless the client project has the connection string, which is not ideal...

Comment: Text templating generator *.Context.tt has template, created default constructor for DBContext .Find something like this  public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>") 
and replace or add your own additional parametrized constructor ( base(connstr) can use name or connection string)

Comment: I've tried moving the EF into a separate project, but could never get it to run unless the Client has the connection strings in its web.config :(

I'm not sure if .Context.tt is still applicable with Code-First model?

Comment: easily let the Connectionstring to be stored in the class library project settings and you for each class library that needs connection string

Answer (score 1):

Connections used by DLLs in you Web API project must be defined in the web.config.
You can use multiple connectionStrings and identify them by name like this:

```
<connectionStrings>   
    <add name="DatabaseOne" connectionString="" />
    <add name="DatabaseTwo" connectionString="" />
<connectionStrings>
```

Next you must configure the DataContext to use the right one:

```
public class ClassLibraryOneDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ClassLibraryOneDbContext()
        : base("DatabaseOne")
    {
    }
}
```

..

```
public class ClassLibraryTwoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ClassLibraryTwoDbContext()
        : base("DatabaseTwo")
    {
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could set it programmatically but that wouldn't by mine advice since this makes it very inflexible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Sam! I'm not sure if that's helping in terms of the problem at hand (unless I'm mistaken). I've got the DB connections working fine, but I am trying to figure out on whether it is possible to remove any reference to EF from the client project and have that contained in a separate DAL project...

Comment: Well yeah sure, do as I sugest and put ClassLibraryOneDbContext in ClassLibraryOne and ClassLibraryTwoDbContext in ClassLibraryTwo. These projects will have a reference to Entity Framework and not your Web API project. Your Web API project will then have a reference to ClassLibraryOne and ClassLibraryTwo

Comment: Oh I see, right - I have tried just this without success, but will have another go to double check and report back. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

From question what I understand is that your Class Library projects have their own DB connections which client will NOT know.

You want your Class Libraries to **some how read these DB connection** information from **some place**, and that **some place** should NOT be client's web.config file.

If my above understanding is correct, then you can have a separate config file, for example `class1project.xml`, and your library will always read this xml file for the connection information.

Your next question might be, how your client will initialize the `DBContext` class from our class library. Since your context class is still looking for a particular connection string in web.config file.

For this you can have your context class' constructor set as `internal` so that your client cannot call it on its own. Then can have some other `static` class in your project with `static` method like `CreateContext` and this method will initialize the context class by passing appropriate connection information which it will read from `class1project.xml` file.